# Reload a child page from parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web

I want a child page(that is opened from a link of parent page) will be reloaded every time from parent page when i click the Reload.

I used this but this don't work when i refresh the parent page.

```
<li><a href="js.php" title="alert-tab"  onclick="myWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');">New Window</a></li>

<li><a href="#" title="alert-tab"  onclick="myWindow.location.reload();">Reload</a></li>
```

Any help on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For security reason you can't read or change (including reload) in modern browsers a window/iframe that was loaded with the URL of another domain (like `htt://google.com`, supposing you're not a Google coder).

So you can't do that except if the distant server [authorized it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control), which isn't frequent.

If the page is on the same domain, this works :

```
<li><a href="#" title="alert-tab"  onclick="myWindow=window.open('index2.html','_blank');">New Window</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="alert-tab"  onclick="myWindow.location.reload();">Reload</a></li>​
```

Be careful in your tests to always open in `http://` (and not `file://`) as 2 local files are always considered as separate domains.

Note that if you give a name to your window, the next time it will be loaded will be in the same window, even if you reloaded the parent page in between :

```
<li><a href="#" title="alert-tab"  onclick="myWindow=window.open('index2.html','someName');">New Window</a></li>
```

So, if you want to have the child page reloaded when you reload the parent page, you could do something like this :

```
<li><a href="#" title="alert-tab" id=mylink>New Window</a></li>
<script>
function openPage(){
    myWindow=window.open('index2.html','someName');
    localStorage['open'] = 'yes';
}
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('mylink').onclick=openPage;
    if (localStorage['open']=='yes')  myWindow=window.open('index2.html','someName');
    localStorage['open'] = 'no';
};
</script>
```

The idea is to check at loading if the child window was open last time and if necessary force its reload.

Of course, this works only if parent and child are served from the same domain.

Comment: what if i want it in same domain @dystroy?

Comment: If it's the same domain (including port), you can do it (see edited answer).

Comment: this worked before! but what i need is there any way if i refresh the parent page after opening new window this can refresh the previously opened window? @dystroy

Comment: What you seem to need may simply be to give your window a name (see answer) or something more complex (see also answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can *reopen* the page, which in most cases have the same effect as reload.

```
<li><a href="js.php" title="alert-tab"  onclick="myWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');">New Window</a></li>

<li><a href="#" title="alert-tab"  onclick="myWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');">Reload</a></li>
```

Comment: But you can't close the last one if it's served from another domain.

Comment: Yes, the user asked how to **reload**