# Refresh child window on parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i refresh child page if parent window reloads?

Suppose **A.html** has a link that opens **B.html**. **B.html** will automatically refresh if **A.html** reloads.

Any javascript/jQuery way?

Comment: Define `opens`. If it's a normal link that opens a window in a new tab, you have no control from A to B. If it's an iFrame, Pranay's answer should work. edit: popup-windows would work too, if you use `window.open`

Comment: i used window.open but problem is how can i check whether parent window is reloaded or not from child window @OptimusCrime?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520954/reload-a-child-page-from-parent-page

Answer (score 1):

You can control the child if you open it like this: (in **A.html**)

```
baby = window.open('B.html');
```

Refreshing the child will then be done like this:

```
baby.history.go(0);
```

If you refresh A, the pages `unload`-event will be invoked. So to refresh B when one refreshes (or leaves or closes, for that matter) A, you can do: (in **A.html**)

```
<body onunload="baby.history.go(0);">
```

But, after the refresh all javascript variables will be lost! It will lose its connection with page B! So it will only work for one time.

I think a solution will be to make a refresh button/link in **A.html**, that will refresh the data on the page (A) dynamically in order to maintain the connection to the child windows (B).